# Facing a Round up TexBox not working C#

Tags: c#, math

TextBox4 will not round up, can you help?

```
        var start_time = textBox6.Text;
        var trailer_count = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        var minutes_apart = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
        var trailers = new List<Trailer__Time>();
        for (var i = 0; i < trailer_count; i++) // CHANGED FROM 1 TO 0
```

Comment: will not round up means??  Can you give example

Comment: Exp; 500/32= 15.62 I want it to say 16

Comment: remove .ToString("0") and .ToString("0.00") from code

Comment: i get the same results I think my problem is here.                                     var trailer_count = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str1 = "500";
string str2 = "32";
int value = (int)Math.Ceiling( Convert.ToDouble(str1) / Convert.ToDouble(str2)); //16
```

You have to first convert strings to `double` or `decimal` values and then pass this result to `Math.Ceailing` with explicit type cast to int. Now you can convert this `value` variable to string or another datatype according to your requirement.

Comment: Im doing this with a 2 textbox and 1 comboBox. how would i add that to the code?

Comment: you can set str1 or str2  to textbox.text or combox.text . its simple

Comment: sorry for the confusion String is is not talking to Var in the code i add more at the top.

Comment: try this. textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString((int)Math.Ceiling( Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.Text)));

Comment: that was perfect thanks for your help. Can you look at my Increment post?